# "Оставьте и получаете" - корректно ли такое сочетание? Нужна ли запятая перед словом "используя"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

**Оставьте online-заявку используя форму выше, и получаете в подарок первую консультацию.**

Корректно ли сочетание глаголов в этом предложении? Нужна ли запятая перед словом "используя"?

Answer (score 3):

Предложение требует правки.

***Оставьте online-заявку, используя форму выше, и получИте в подарок первую консультацию.***

Деепричастный оборот "используя форму выше" нужно выделить запятыми. Глаголы- сказуемые должны быть одного вида (в данном случае совершенного) и желательно одной формы.

Возможно иное  прочтение данного предложения:

***Оставьте online-заявку, используя форму выше, и полУчите в подарок первую консультацию.***

Но первый вариант лучше.

Answer (score 1):

**Оставьте online-заявку, используя форму выше, и получИте в подарок первую консультацию.**

1) Это предложение можно рассматривать как сложное предложение или предложение с однородными членами. Но в любом случае союз И выражает одновременные или последовательные действия, поэтому форма несовершенного вида **получаете** сюда не подойдет.

В то же время  авторам хочется ясно обозначить **одновременность событий**, а форма глагола *получите* зависит от ударения, которое вроде бы надо поставить для однозначности прочтения.

2) Для необособления распространенного деепричастного оборота нет причин.

Answer (score 0):

Сочетание "оставьте и получаете" некорректно. Возможные варианты:

(1) "Оставьте и получи́те" (однородные сказуемые)

(2) "Оставляете и получаете" (однородные сказуемые)

(3) "Оставьте, и полу́чите" или "оставьте — и полу́чите" (действие — результат)

"Используя форму выше" — деепричастный оборот. Он должен выделяться запятыми.

Мой вариант:

**Оставьте online-заявку, используя форму выше, и получите в подарок первую консультацию.**

(ударение по вашему выбору)